# mGPU (Multi-GPU) AFR with RTX 2060 & D3D12 possible?

Tags: directx, nvidia, direct3d, vulkan, direct3d12

Is it possible to do AFR in D3D12 with two RTX 2060 graphics cards?

I have a custom rendering framework that supports AFR with D3D12 but just read Nvidia dropped SLI support however I'm having trouble finding a clear answer as to what this means when it comes to D3D12 / Vulkan APIs. Did they drop just SLI driver support but Linked-GPU support still works as normal in D3D12?

If I buy two RTX 2060 graphics cards can I set them up as a "**GPU 0 (Link 0) & GPU 1 (Link 0)**" in Windows and then in D3D12 use them as a node group?

I want to add RayTracing into my API but want to test AFR / mGPU support with it & Nvidia has made this very unclear about what this means for D3D12 / Vulkan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you can't use Linked GPUs to do AFR with these GPUs without driver hacks.
However I can do AFR by creating two D3D12 devices & manually do the swapping & copping of buffers.

This will also allow me to do cross GPU vendor AFR rendering as well.

Will my API I'm creating support this? Yes, yes it will ;)